# How to use the new onReset overload on AndroidView in compose to reuse ExoPlayer inside a VerticalPager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer

I want to use `ExoPlayer` inside an `AndroidView` in Jetpack Compose inside a `VerticalPager` and use the new onReset feature on AndroidView to reuse the exoplayer views.

The docs say that it's supported by the various LazyLists but says nothing about VerticalPager/HorizontalPager.

Since this is a very new feature, the documentation seems to be scarce.

```
AndroidView(
     factory = {
          Logger.d { "PlayerView factory created" }
          PlayerView(context).apply {
              hideController()
              useController = false
              player = exoPlayer
              resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM
              layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)
              clipToOutline = true
          }
       },
       onReset = {
           Logger.d { "" }
           (it.player as ExoPlayer).apply {
               val defaultDataSourceFactor = DefaultDataSource.Factory(context)
               val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(
                            context,
                            defaultDataSourceFactor
                        )
               val source = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(video.url))
               setMediaSource(source)
               repeatMode = REPEAT_MODE_ONE
               prepare()
            }
        },
        onRelease = {
            Logger.d { "PlayerView factory released" }
        }
)
```

But this is only giving me out of memory errors.

What should I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Reuse will work inside Pagers as well

I am not sure what you are trying to do in onReset block, inside onReset you are supposed to reset the previously active video playing as the previous content is not associated with this View anymore. You need to start the video play inside update block - another param AndroidView has